# How to imprison Heroes?

Tags: impire

As the Title states, **How can I imprison Heroes or Extract them for that matter?**

In the game it says to mark the Heroes by right clicking them with the option to either Send to Prison or Extract. It also Says to set your squads with the Prison Mark or Extract Mark depending on how you want them to handle it. I'm probably doing something wrong just can't figure it out.

---

Not sure what I did but I was able to imprison the last 3 heroes that attacked me. Somewhat confused now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click a hero and select the ball and chain for imprisonment, or the skull and crossbones for extraction.

Note that you'll need an intact prison and/or extractor in order for the option to be available.

Also, choosing the archery target will move them to your training rooms so your minions can use them as live target practice - the only way for them to reach level 3 in the training room.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this an answer. He already said he used the ball an chain icon on the heroes, so did I. My minions just kill them instead of taking them to the prison (even though the squad is also on jail duty from squad menu)

Comment: Are you sure? Downed enemies always turn into loot bags. Your imp minions then haul them to the stockroom or prison or training rooms depending on what you ordered done.

Answer (score 1):

In the squads menu, each squad can be set a mark. This can be done for each hero in its context menu. But you already knew that. The icon changes the loot. The box makes a resource bag. The ball and chain makes it drop a bag, that will be taken to prison and converted to treasure. The skull makes the bag be made to DEC points. The target causes the bag to allow the training room to make lvl 3 units for 3 mins. Either way, the loot is always a bag.